# Having trouble setting up drag listener | Kotlin | Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I’ve been searching for anything I can find on drag listeners, but all I found was the android studio guide which further confused me.

I’m trying to get this to work `dashboard.setOnDragListener()`  (dashboard is just a cardview), but I’m confused by the parameters it needs, the error I get: `No value passed for parameter ‘l’`

I think the documentation mentioned 2 more parameters, but I’m lost

If I can get better help than what I got from the documentation I’ll be a happy man

MainActivity.kt:

`var dashboard = findViewById<View>(R.id.dashboard)`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the target view that receives drag-and-drops gets the drag listener. The views that will be dragged get a call to startDragAndDrop.

Here's what mine looks like:

```
inner class MyDragListener(): View.OnDragListener {
        override fun onDrag(view: View?, dragEvent: DragEvent?): Boolean {

            //you might also want to use this if to distinguish between different views that might be dragged
            if (dragEvent!!.action==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP)
            {
                //do stuff here
                return true
            }

    }
```

Then for the views that are getting dragged, register them for the dragging operation like this.

```
dragableView.setOnLongClickListener({
                //here you could add some effects for 
                //hinting to the user that something is being dragged.
                //I like to use a vibrator and toggle the visibility  
                //of something else on the screen
                val dbs= View.DragShadowBuilder(it)
                var clipData= ClipData.newPlainText("","")
                it.startDragAndDrop(clipData,dbs,it,0)
            })
```

Oh right, I almost forgot. Pass your draglistener to the target.

```
dashboard.setOnDragListener(MyDragListener())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img?.setOnDragListener { view, dragEvent ->
            when (dragEvent.action) {
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED")
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED")
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED")
                }
                DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION")
                }
            }
            true
        }
```